# angularjs phonecat tutorial step 5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am reading the angularjs phonecat tutorial. I am currently on the [step 5](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05).

In the section "Test", I've found this piece of code:

```
describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {

describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){
  var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

  // Load our app module definition before each test.
  beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));

  // The injector ignores leading and trailing underscores here (i.e. _$httpBackend_).
  // This allows us to inject a service but then attach it to a variable
  // with the same name as the service in order to avoid a name conflict.
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpBackend.expectGET('phones/phones.json').
        respond([{name: 'Nexus S'}, {name: 'Motorola DROID'}]);

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope: scope});
  }));
```

I can't understand the reason to create the *$httpBackend* var. Can you guys explain me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$httpBackend` needs to be accessible in all `it` test definitions later on. Thus it has to be in a parent closure of the `it` calls you'll write bellow.

`beforeEach` is the place where you do stuff that applies to all `it` calls so it is a sensible place to initialize `$httpBackend`.

Regarding the comment above it, if the parameter to `inject` would be named `$httpBackend` then inside that anonymous function you wouldn't have access to the "global" one (that's how closures work in JavaScript), so you would not be able to initialize it.
Thus the people who wrote `inject` added this "magic" functionality regarding leading and trailing underscores, so that you can name it differently from the global variable that you need to initialize inside.

[I'd recommend reading this to better understand closures.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)